# Text displayed inline after the icon in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im stuck with this:

```
<span class="ViewsInfo">
<span>2100</span>
<icon class="icon-eye-open"></i>
</span>
```

In this variant, the text is displayed before the icon in one line. But I need the text to be after the icon and to be displayed inline at the same time.
Unfortunately, when I edit like that:

```
<span class="ViewsInfo">
<icon class="icon-eye-open"></i>
<span>2100</span>
</span>
```

The icon and the text just melt together in one mass and nothing is clear. I tried different paddings for both icons and ViewsInfo class, but it didnt help. Where am I wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**EDITED**
LOL. SO is miraculous:).After smth like ~20 seconds I posted this and idead came to my mind and I realised that the code is to be like this

```
<span>
<icon class="icon-eye-open"></i>
</span>
<span class="ViewsInfo">2100</span>
```

Hopefully I am helping someone further.

Comment: Try `<span class="ViewsInfo">
<span><icon class="icon-eye-open"></i>2100</span>
</span>`

Comment: I think it's `<i ...` not `<icon ...`.

Comment: If you figured it out yourself, please post it as an answer below so that you can accept it later and the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<span class="ViewsInfo">
  <icon class="icon-eye-open"/>
  <br/>
  <span>2100</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<span class="ViewsInfo">
  <i class="icon-eye-open"></i> Edit
</span>
```

See: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons